# vue-awesome-swiper / The button name is shared, so other swiper move as well

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, swiper.js

```
<template>
  <swiper v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 4</swiper-slide>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
             //sample items
        items: [ 
          {
            1:1
          },
          {
            2:2
          },
          {
            3:3
          },
        ],
        swiperOption: {
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

v-for creates a lot of swippers.
However, the button name overlaps, so the swiper all moves together.

I looked for something in Swiper API that could solve this problem, but I couldn't.

Please help me if there is a way to solve this problem.....

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique names, try adding the unique key to the ref:

```
:ref="'mySwiper' + item.id"
```

Adding the colon (shortcut for v-bind) enables the use of `item.id` as a variable.